# How to access services logs from my C# test?

Tags: c#, wcf, testing, event-log

There is a WCF service that I'm testing.  When the service completes it posts its results on an application services log- I can see the message in the Event Viewer.

I'd like to monitor the log and read the log entry from my test program, but I haven't been able to figure out the best way to do that.  I've searched through StackOverflow archives and Google.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  I'm coding in C#.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has a KB article on how to read event log entries from code:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6b9a7h8(v=VS.90).aspx

In short:

```
// Create an EventLog instance and assign its log name.
EventLog myLog = new EventLog("MyLogName");

// Read the event log entries.
foreach (EventLogEntry entry in myLog.Entries)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\tEntry: " + entry.Message);
}
```

(code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9hdxtte.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and sorry I didn't respond to you as quickly.  I will try this when I get in to work later in the morning.